# Multiplatform app development with individual guis

Tags: android, qt, user-interface, mobile, multiplatform

I am currently planning the development of a multiplatform app, and I am not sure wich way to do it fits my requirements best, since all possibilties I could think of failed to satisfy me.

First I want to write an app for android, which should feel like a normal typical android app. So I want to use the standard actionbar and android design look and feel in my other gui elements. After finishing the android app I am planning on developing an ios app, which should have a different design, so i am going to redevelop the gui for this anyway.

But I don´t want to rewrite the other code wich represents the intelligence of the app, independent from the gui.  I came up with the following possibilities:

### 1. Java GUI With native library

Here I abstract all the code of my app in a C++ library (since as far as I know ios supports the usage of c++ libraries too) and develop the gui android typically in java. The library would than have a function to start and would inform the gui about every change via callback functions.

**Pro**

- I can reuse all the code that would be the same on both platforms. I just would implement the gui seperately
- The design of the android gui is straightforward as I want it to be. It looks like typical android because it is typical android.

**Cons**

- I dislike the usage of JNI very much. Especially the signature and names of the callback functions (calling java functions from c++) are not checked at compile time and require a lot of manual work. If I rename a function and forget to rework the native part I only notice this mistake at runtime.

### 2. Build the GUI on the native side

Here I had difficulties finding out what is possible, especially for 2.2

## 2.1 Use Qt

I have only a few first step experiences with Qt in general but as far as I understood i would have the following pros and cons:

**Pro**

Reuse most parts of the code for ios and Android. I would than redesign the gui for each platform to make them feel natural. I can´t evaluate how much qt may even assists me at doing that

**Cons**

I have to copy the android gui by using other qt widgets. This is more effort and I don´t know if one can replicate the android gui elements (like the actionbar) so that the user wouldn´t notice it.

## 2.2 Using the android framework from the native side

I dont know if this is possible at all, I wasn´t able to find this information. Can I use the class "NativeActivity" and use the android framework to build the gui and use e.g. the actionbar? If this is possible somehow it would have the pros from 1. and maybe wouldn´t have it cons?

---

Do you have any feedback to my ideas or maybe even new approaches I didn´t think of? How do other multiplatform apps like WhatsApp solve this problem? Do they have redundant code for each platform?

Thank you,
Tobi

Comment: Write the UI's for each platform natively to their platform. Then your apps logic could be a dependency used for each platform. Otherwise, you could use an abstraction framework, perhaps PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it depends very much on your application requirements. By my opinion, a better solution is to develop a separate application for each platform using recommended SDK's for that platform, and implement in native C++ only the time consuming data processing algorithms.

Application runtime on mobile platforms is not so straightforward as on desktop platforms. You should take into account background and foreground processing, specific application life cycling, accessing system resources such as network, file system, etc. And all these issues do differ on iOS and Android.

Regarding possibilities that you listed.

1. Qt/QML is ok only in case two requirements are met:

   1.1 Your application is a foregroud application without any background operations.

   1.2 You purchase a commercial Qt license because only commercial Qt can be submitted to Apple iTunes app store (even GPL apps are under
   question).
2. Using NDK Native Activities on Android with cross-platform C/C++ backend. Android NDK API offers much less API then Android Java SDK, so a lot of things you will have to implement or wrap manually. It is a hard road.
3. Mixing Java code and C/C++ using JNI gives you more of Android SDK API. But you should remember that an Android activity's life cycle is not somewhat that you're used to deal with when developing on C/C++.

**Approach that we are using**

We've been developing an application with a huge amount of cross platform functionality that should work on Windows/Linux/Mac OSx/Android/iOS. We're using the approach as follows.

1. Cross-platform core is written in pure C++.
2. We have adaptors to GUI interface for each platform.
3. On desktop we use Qt as it reaches all desktop platforms with minor adapting to each platform.
4. On iOS the GUI is built using iOS SDK with Objective-C and C++ core is linked as a Framework. Still, we had to patch our core in some way for iOS background requirements and so.
5. On Android we wrap our C++ core in a background process and build all the GUI using only Android Java SDK. Foreground GUI activities interact with the core via local sockets, so we don't need to bother with activities life cycling in our C++ core. But the adaptor is a litle bit complicated.

Nevertheless, both mobile platforms often require workarounds and adaptations in C++ core which add a number of #ifdef'ed branches in code for each platform.